# Is using row or col in other elements than a div considered a bad practice?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is it considered a bad practice to use `row` or `col` on other elements than a div? Maybe a `span` might be still fine, but elements like `a` or `p`?

Answer (score 0):

[Here an output Top Row using col on `a` tags and bottom using `div` tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71gHE.png)

Those are basically classes so you could use them as you please,
But if you working on something down the line next guy that going to work on it wont like it.

(imo its a bad practice since, generally you would be expecting a div there not `a` or `p` tags)